# Клик над изображением canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Есть несколько изображений, которые можно перемещать с помощью мыши по canvas. Но если клик происходит над двумя рисунками одновременно то они тянутся оба. Как отловить клик над рисунком что сверху?

Comment: какой язык и GUI ?

Comment: делаю для сайта. html, js